# How to compare two data frames/tables and extract data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, data.table, mismatch

In attempt to extract mismatches between the two data frames below I've already managed to create a new data frame in which mismatches are replaced.
What I need now is a list of mismatches:

```
dfA <- structure(list(animal1 = c("AA", "TT", "AG", "CA"), animal2 = c("AA", "TB", "AG", "CA"), animal3 = c("AA", "TT", "AG", "CA")), .Names = c("animal1", "animal2", "animal3"), row.names = c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3", "snp4"), class = "data.frame")
# > dfA
#      animal1 animal2 animal3
# snp1      AA      AA      AA
# snp2      TT      TB      TT
# snp3      AG      AG      AG
# snp4      CA      CA      CA
dfB <- structure(list(animal1 = c("AA", "TT", "AG", "CA"), animal2 = c("AA", "TB", "AG", "DF"), animal3 = c("AA", "TB", "AG", "DF")), .Names = c("animal1", "animal2", "animal3"), row.names = c("snp1", "snp2", "snp3", "snp4"), class = "data.frame")
#> dfB
#     animal1 animal2 animal3
#snp1      AA      AA      AA
#snp2      TT      TB      TB
#snp3      AG      AG      AG
#snp4      CA      DF      DF
```

To clarify the mismatches, here they are marked as 00's:

```
#      animal1 animal2 animal3
# snp1      AA      AA      AA
# snp2      TT      TB      00
# snp3      AG      AG      AG
# snp4      CA      00      00
```

I need the following output:

```
structure(list(snpname = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("snp2", "snp4"), class = "factor"), animalname = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("animal2", "animal3"), class = "factor"), alleledfA = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CA", "TT"), class = "factor"), alleledfB = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DF", "TB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("snpname", "animalname", "alleledfA", "alleledfB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
#  snpname animalname alleledfA alleledfB
#1    snp2    animal3        TT        TB
#2    snp4    animal2        CA        DF
#3    snp4    animal3        CA        DF
```

So far I've been trying to extract additional data out of my `lapply` function which I use to replace the mismatches by zero, without success though. I also tried to write an ifelse function without success. Hope you guys can help me out here!

Eventually this will be run for data sets with a dimension of 100K by 1000, so efficiency is a pro

Comment: Your clarification can produced by: `ifelse(as.matrix(dfA) == as.matrix(dfB), as.matrix(dfA), "00")`

Comment: Do the rownames of `dfA` always match the rownames of `dfB`?

Comment: @lukeA yes, I create two subsets in which both the row- and column names will always match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has `data.table` tag, so here's my attempt using this package. First step is to convert row names to columns as `data.table` don't like those, then converting to long format after `rbind`ing and setting an id per data set, finding where there are more than one unique value and converting back to a wide format

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(dfA, keep.rownames = TRUE) 
setDT(dfB, keep.rownames = TRUE)   

dcast(melt(rbind(dfA, 
                 dfB, 
                 idcol = TRUE), 
           id = 1:2
           )[, 
             if(uniqueN(value) > 1L) .SD, 
             by = .(rn, variable)], 
      rn + variable ~ .id)

#      rn variable  1  2
# 1: snp2  animal3 TT TB
# 2: snp4  animal2 CA DF
# 3: snp4  animal3 CA DF
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using array.indices of a matrix:

```
i.arr <- which(dfA != dfB, arr.ind=TRUE)

data.frame(snp=rownames(dfA)[i.arr[,1]], animal=colnames(dfA)[i.arr[,2]],
           A=dfA[i.arr], B=dfB[i.arr])
#   snp  animal  A  B
#1 snp4 animal2 CA DF
#2 snp2 animal3 TT TB
#3 snp4 animal3 CA DF
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `dplyr/tidyr` using a similar approach as in @David Arenburg's post.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(add_rownames(dfA), add_rownames(dfB)) %>% 
          gather(Var, Val, -rowname) %>%
          group_by(rowname, Var) %>%
          filter(n_distinct(Val)>1) %>% 
          mutate(id = 1:2) %>% 
          spread(id, Val)
#  rowname     Var     1     2
#    (chr)   (chr) (chr) (chr)
#1    snp2 animal3    TT    TB
#2    snp4 animal2    CA    DF
#3    snp4 animal3    CA    DF
```